Hotbed turning off during print
I have an Ender 3 Max Neo printer that's been printing things for over a year without anything unusual happening.  Out of my past 4 prints, I've been alerted to an error from a continuous beep and an error message saying: Hotbed temperature is too low.
Pushing the confirm button does nothing and I have to turn the machine off and back on again, at which point I'm given the option to resume print, and then everything heats back up and resumes.  After some testing I've determined that it's happening somewhere between a little over 4 hours into the print job.  For a print of over 8 h, the error will occur again after about 4 hours.
Printer isn't connected to anything, and there's been no firmware updates done to it since I got it.  Haven't messed around with any parts of the printer in months. Print job it first happened on was one that I had previously printed from the same file twice before without any issues, including just the day before.
Any suggestions on where to start checking would be greatly appreciated.

Have you checked the cable powering the bed? After a while these may get loose or break (inside the plastic cover) causing failing heating the bed.
The same is applicable to the thermistor leads, linking in the cables may produce unwanted side effects die to shorting of the wires.
Replacing the cables should fix this issue.

I will take a look at them, it just seems odd that it is only occurs after 4 h and turning of and on completely resets

Time repeatable problems like this are typically an intermittent connection that is undergoing thermal expansion and "fixes" itself when it cools.  Replacing it (when you can find "it") should fix it.
